# RegExp to get matched values

Tags: javascript

I am having problem with RegExp in javascript. I want to get output matches by value. Example:

```
'/xyz/1/2'.match(/\/xyz\/[\d+]\/[\d+]/)
```

It outputs: ["/xyz/1/2"]

But I want to get matched values: ["1", "2"].

Please give me the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a group of characters by adding brackets:

```
'/xyz/1/2'.match(/\/xyz\/([\d+])\/([\d+])/)
```